# Internet Explorer 11 Live Tile Caching and Expirations

Tags: caching, internet-explorer-11, live, tiles

I am creating a Live Tile through a pinned site with IE 11 on Windows 8.1. I'm using meta tags to achieve this:

```
<meta name="application-name" content="..." />
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content=" #768591" />
<meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="..." />
<meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="..." />
<meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="..." />
<meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="..." />
<meta name="msapplication-notification" content="frequency=30; polling-uri=...;id=1;cycle=1;" />
```

(the ellipsis is where my urls are going)

My live tiles are working and receiving updates through my uri that I include in the polling-uri field. However, windows is caching those notifications every 30 minutes and replaying the static update on the live tile. This is really annoying since the live tile is set to display the status of my web app... Old information is confusing and irrelevant. Is there an xml field I can specify so windows doesn't cache old notifications?

This is what my xml currently looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tile>
  <visual lang="en-US" version="2">
    <binding template="TileSquare150x150PeekImageAndText02" fallback="TileSquarePeekImageAndText02">
      <image id="1" src="..." />
      <text id="1">ONLINE</text>
      <text id="2">1:07 PM</text>
    </binding>
    <binding template="TileWide310x150SmallImageAndText02" fallback="TileWideSmallImageAndText02">
      <image id="1" src="..." />
      <text id="1">...</text>
      <text id="2">ONLINE</text>
      <text id="3">Checked at 1:07 PM</text>
    </binding>
    <binding template="TileSquare310x310SmallImageAndText01">
      <image id="1" src="..." />
      <text id="1">...</text>
      <text id="2">ONLINE</text>
      <text id="3">Checked at 1:07 PM</text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
</tile>
```

Thanks for your help!

Also, if anyone was wondering where the cached information is stored, it's located in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Notifications\appdb.dat
Unfortunately, you can't just delete this file or remove the cached information because that file is always open by explorer.exe (since it's constantly writing cache information into it). Also the group policy for deleting history on logout won't work for this since the computer will always be logged in.